# Eclipse 3.5.1 RCP Styled string not updating in package navigator

Tags: plugins, eclipse-rcp, java-6

I have a problem presumably with eclipse 3.5.1. I have a plugin that, besides other things, adds a string decoration to files that have been changed. Everything works fine in eclipse 3.7.1, but on the target application which stands on eclipse 3.5.1 the navigator does not display the styled string correctly.

The code for string decorations is as follows (it also adds the file version, which also does not work on eclipse 3.5.1):

```
public class CustomLabelProvider extends ResourceExtensionLabelProvider implements
    org.eclipse.jface.viewers.DelegatingStyledCellLabelProvider.IStyledLabelProvider {

@Override
public StyledString getStyledText(Object element) {

    StyledString label = new StyledString();

    try {
        Set modifiedFiles =
                CustomContentProvider.getModifiedSegments().get(
                        ((Resource) element).toString().substring(1));
        if ((modifiedFiles != null) && (modifiedFiles.size() > 0)) {
            label.append(">", StyledString.DECORATIONS_STYLER);
        }
        label.append(getText(element));
        if (element instanceof ExtendedFile) {
            Integer fileVersion = ((ExtendedFile) element).getFileVersion();
            if (fileVersion != null) {
                label.append("  ").append(fileVersion.toString(), StyledString.DECORATIONS_STYLER);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return label;
}
```

A comparison between both eclipse versions:

[image: eclipse 3.5.1]

[image: eclipse 3.7.1]

Both eclipse 3.5.1 and 3.7.1 implement IStyledLabelProvider. The plugin starts in both eclipse versions, osgi lists it as ACTIVE, and there is some logging that I cut out, that works in both eclipse versions. What could be the reason for this behaviour?

**UPDATE**: The label provider plugin.xml

```xml
<plugin>
<extension
        point="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.viewer">
      <viewer
           viewerId="myApplication.NavigatorView">
      </viewer>

      <viewerContentBinding viewerId="myApplication.NavigatorView">
         <includes>                    
            <contentExtension pattern="NavigatorLabelProvider.NavigatorContent"/>
         </includes>
      </viewerContentBinding>
</extension>

<extension  
     point="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.navigatorContent">

      <navigatorContent
           name="myNavigatorContent"            
           activeByDefault="true"
           contentProvider="labelprovider.CustomContentProvider"
            labelProvider="labelprovider.CustomLabelProvider"                                      
           id="NavigatorLabelProvider.NavigatorContent">        
                  <enablement>
                         <or>        
                            <adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject" />
                            <instanceof
                                        value="org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource" />
                         </or>
         </enablement>

        <commonSorter
             class="org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.resources.workbench.ResourceExtensionSorter"
             id="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources.sorters.defaultSorter">
           <parentExpression>
                          <or>          
                            <instanceof value="org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource" />
                         </or>
                   </parentExpression>
        </commonSorter>
        <dropAssistant
             class="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources.ResourceDropAdapterAssistant"
             id="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources.resourceDropAdapter">
           <possibleDropTargets>
              <or>
                 <adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject"/>
                 <adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IFolder"/>
                 <adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile"/>
              </or>
           </possibleDropTargets>
        </dropAssistant>        

        <actionProvider
             class="org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.resources.actions.EditActionProvider"
             id="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources.actions.EditActions"/>        
        <actionProvider
             class="org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.resources.actions.RefactorActionProvider"
             id="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources.actions.RefactorActions"/>        

              <!-- Menu Shortcut Actions for Wizards -->
              <commonWizard
                                type="new"
                                        wizardId="org.eclipse.ui.wizards.new.folder">
                                <enablement>
                                        <or>
                                                <adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile" />      
                                                <adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IFolder" />
                                        <adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject" />
                                <adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IWorkspaceRoot" />     
                                        </or>
                         </enablement>
                        </commonWizard>  
                <commonWizard
                    type="new"
                    wizardId="org.eclipse.ui.wizards.new.file">
                                <enablement>
                                        <or>
                                                <adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile" />      
                                                <adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IFolder" />
                                        <adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject" />
                                <adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IWorkspaceRoot" />     
                                        </or>
                         </enablement>
                        </commonWizard>                      
      </navigatorContent>
   </extension>
</plugin>
```

Comment: What view is this? How are you setting up the label provider?

Comment: It's a custom Navigator view. The binding of custom label provider happens in the plugin.xml.

Comment: Show us the setup in the plugin.xml

Comment: I updated the question with the plugin.xml file, although I don't really see how it helps. I would have to post the entire code for it to make any sense and there is just no point in doing that. Another hint that maybe could help is that I run the eclipse 3.7.1 from Eclipse RCP, and the 3.5.1 from a deployed, standalone eclipse application.

Comment: Have you built this using a 3.5.1 target platform to check that everything exists on 3.5.1?

Comment: It's an old application. The reason I'm using eclipse 3.7.1 for further development is that there were some problems with setting up eclipse 3.5.1, due to changes made over time to the project. This does lead to some conflicts, and I was wondering if this version discrepancy might be the reason for this particular problem. We are planning on moving the application to Eclipse 4.x RCP, so I guess that could potentially solve the problem.

Comment: If you are going to move to 4.x you must stop using internal classes such as `ResourceExtensionLabelProvider`. The Eclipse internals have been very largely rewritten and many old internal classes no longer exist.